# How to write html elements using javascript after "window.history.go(-1)"?

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, deployment

I want to print the validation message on the div box after "window.history.go(-1)".

I wrote a function writediv() to write the message on the div element but I think It's not working because the previous page is displaying when writediv() implement for the present page. I haven't a clear idea to write on div after "window.history.go(-1)". Can you give me some assistance? It's very helpful.

Here is the function

```
function writediv(){
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Invalid Credintials";
    }
```

Here is the code,

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ){
        
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
      
       
        $conn= new mysqli('localhost','root','','shop');

        if($conn->connect_error){
            die('Connection Failed : '.$conn->connect_error);
        }else{
            $stmt=$conn->prepare("select customer_id,username from customer where username=? and password=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['customer_id'];
                    header("Location:home.php");
                    exit();

                }
            }
            else{
                //$_SESSION["errorMessage"] = "Invalid Credentials"; ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                window.history.go(-1);
                
                //document.getElementById("message").outerHTML = "*required";
                writediv();
                </script> 
            <?php 
             
            }  
            
            
        }
    }
?>  


<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cake Easy</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
        
        <script>  
        function validateform(){  
        var username=document.login.username.value;  
        var password=document.login.password.value;  
  
        if (username==null || username==""){
            document.getElementById("user_info").innerHTML = "*required";
            //alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");    
            return false;  
        } 
        if (password==null || password==""){
            document.getElementById("password_info").innerHTML = "*required";
            //alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");    
            return false;  
        } 
        }  
        function writediv(){
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Invalid Credintials";
        }

</script>
    </head>

    <header>Welcome to Cake Easy </header>

    <body>
        
        <form  onsubmit="return validateform()" action="login3.php" method="post" class="formbox" name="login">

            <div id="message" class="label1"></div>
            Username  <span id="user_info" style="color:red"></span><br>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></input><br><br>
            
            Password  <span id="password_info" style="color:red"></span><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></input><br><br>   
            forgotten your username or password?<br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in"></input><br><br>
            New member? <a href="registration.html">Register</a> here.
        </form>
    </body>
            
</html>
```

Comment: You'd have to write it on the page you're going back to, or write it before you go back

Comment: it navigates to the same page after going back.

Comment: OK, well you have to make it run as part of the page loading process then. If it needs data from the current execution of the page, you could put it in localstorage and then retrieve it. Bit of a strange design though, making a page go back to itself, IMHO

Comment: Thank you soo much. I fixed it after your advice. Very valuable for me.

Comment: Why not simply use PHP to do the redirection & printing of error message rather than `history.go(-1)` ?

Comment: because when I submit the button with invalid credentials, another login form appears.

Comment: I see no reason why you could not do that in PHP and simply use Javascript to popup an alert once redirected. That said, you are storing the user's passwords in plain text rather than hashing them - perhaps you will address that at some point?